# how many color combinations in a 24 bit image

Tags: c++, c, byte, bit

I am reading a book and I am not sure if its a mistake or I am misunderstanding the quote. It reads...

> Nowadays every PC you can buy has
>   hardware that can render images with
>   at least 16.7 million individual
>   colors. Rather than have an array with
>   thousands of color entries, the images
>   instead contain explicit color values
>   for each pixel. A 24-bit display, of
>   course, uses 24 bits, or 3 bytes per
>   pixel, for color information. This
>   gives 1 byte, or 256 distinct values
>   each, for red, green, and blue. This
>   is generally called true color,
>   because 256^3 (16.7 million)

He says 1 byte is equal to 256 distinct values. 1 byte = 8 bits. 8^2 bits = 64 combinations of colors right ?? It's not adding up right to me. I know it might be something simple to understand, but I don't understand.

Comment: `javascript:alert(Math.pow(2,24));` = `16,777,216`

Comment: 256 reds * 256 blues * 256 greens = 16,777,216 colors

Comment: 2^8 not 8^2 that was your confusion :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The combinations of 8 bits is not 8<sup>2</sup> (64) but 2<sup>8</sup> (256). This is because each of the 8 bits can have 2 distinct values. For 1 bit that would give you 2 (2<sup>1</sup>) possibilities, for 2 bits 2*2 (2<sup>2</sup>), for 3 bits 2*2*2 (2<sup>3</sup>)... etc. 3 bytes = 24 bits => 2<sup>24</sup> = 16.7M possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 byte = 8 bits = 2^8 = 256 combinations :)

24 bit combinations = 2^24 = Three 8 bit colors = 256^3 = 16777216 ~= 16.7 million color combinations
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 24 bits for the color information you can display 2^24 colors = 16.7 million!