# how many color combinations in a 24 bit image

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how many color combinations in a 24 bit image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892303/how-many-color-combinations-in-a-24-bit-image)

I am reading a book and I am not sure if its a mistake or I am misunderstanding the quote. It reads...

> Nowadays every PC you can buy has
>   hardware that can render images with
>   at least 16.7 million individual
>   colors. Rather than have an array with
>   thousands of color entries, the images
>   instead contain explicit color values
>   for each pixel. A 24-bit display, of
>   course, uses 24 bits, or 3 bytes per
>   pixel, for color information. This
>   gives 1 byte, or 256 distinct values
>   each, for red, green, and blue. This
>   is generally called true color,
>   because 256^3 (16.7 million)

He says 1 byte is equal to 256 distinct values. 1 byte = 8 bits. 8^2 bits = 64 distinct colors right ?? It's not adding up right to me. I know it might be something simple to understand, but I don't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of the red, green, and blue bands has `2^8` (**not** `8^2`!) possible values, that is, 256 distinct possibilities.  IOW, with one byte you can "count" from 0 to 255.

So your problem is just that you're confusing the base and exponent involved in the raise-to-power operation in question.

Answer (score 1):

Its not 8^2 , but its 2^8 = 256.